# Angular Form Validations with multiple Routes

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

How can I do Angular forms validations for multiple routes?
For example, I have one big form, it contains several sections like tabs, and I can navigate to them in any moment. 
I use rooting for like navigation.
E.g. I have template, which include and about 5 tabs.

When I fill all inputs I sent data to the server, the server validates my data and if I data had errors, server sent it to front end like JSON which contains errors array with objects like this

{"field": "some input", "message": "some error message"}

I parse this answer, and search form control from the form by a field value, and add error message. But I can do it, for one tab, because in the one moment I have active route only one tab, and I have the form control only for this tab, but how I can load other tabs, in a background and get their form control, and set the error message for them?

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

I tried to find an answer on the Internet, but I could not find anything specific. I find only one article with the same problem http://heidloff.net/article/angular-2-form-redux-multiple-routes, but really there is no other option, only how to use Redux?

**[UPDATE]**

I solved my problem. I deleted tab routes from form, and add all components of tabs in root form component, where early was

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And added **[hidden]** directive to each tab, it is **important**, if adding *ngIf, then we have the same problem like with **router-outlet**, because we will not have access to component while condition in *ngIf will not true.

And I made javascript class with constants for each tab, and add activeTab property to root component form, and I change activeTab  when click on the tab, and form for this tab shows.

In this way I have access to all tabs components and when I did request to server and server return to me response with errors I can processing it in root form component and apply to child form components

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to Subject. But in which case u need this ? If u change tab u reinitalize ur component. U should to save all ur errors in CommonService and reed errors from Service when component loaded.

```
export class PaymentService {

    formErrors: any = {}

    constructor() { }

    setErrors(errors: any) {
        this.formErrors = errors;
    }

    getErrors() { 
        return this.formErrors
    }

 }
```

Comment: Alex, I need it when I open my first tab and click on the button, which saves form of all tabs. And I should give errors, because I didn't fill all required fields on other tabs, and I want to highlight tabs, which has errors, and when I navigate to this tab, I want to see all validation messages below invalid fields. And another case, when I fill all tabs and send the form to the server and when the server returns the answer with errors like object which contains a name of the field and error message I need to apply this messages to fields and highlight tabs with errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about one implementation, I have model objects in Angular and on Server like separated by tabs. e.g. I have one root model object and it contains model objects from each tab. When I filled one tab and send my model to the server, the server gives me error object which will contain a name of the tab with errors and fields. When I get the answer from the server, I will see a name of the tab with errors, and I will highlight this tab after that I will save all errors in service how did **Alex Kvitchastiy** suggest. When I will navigate to tab, I will use AfterViewInit hook and get errors for this tab from common service, and if it will have errors, I will apply it to controls of the tab.

But this implementation has one problem. If I want to disable my button which saves form while I didn't fill all required fields? I don't understand how I can do it if I located in one tab and have access to form controls for one tab because other controls from other tabs didin't be loaded.